# JavaScript change global variable

Tags: javascript

I have 2 JS files, I need to pass 2 variables from one to the other. For that I declared the variables as global in B.js and just tried to change them from A.js. This didn't work. (I have referenced both files correctly in the html). Now I'm trying to change the vars from B.js by calling a function from A.js and passing the vars as parameters.

B.js:

```
var re = '';
var un = '';

function init(response_string, username_string) {
   re = response_string;
   un = username_string;
}
```

A.js:

```
init(response, un);
```

The function in B.js gets the parameters correctly, however I can't seem to find a way to change the global variables. They remain as "".

EDIT: The values I parse from A.js are non-empty strings. I also tried this: `init('test', 'test');`
But the global variables still weren't affected.

EDIT 2:
Heres more code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
<script src="A.js"></script>
<script src="B.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" name="" id="inp">
<a href="" onclick="pass()">Go</a>


</body>

</html>
```

A.js:

```
function pass() {
var text = document.getElementById('inp').value;
pass2(text);
}
```

B.js:

```
var global_string = '';

function pass2(v) {
console.log(v);
global_string = v;
}
```

Comment: Show us a [mcve] that reproduces problem. What you have shown has one undefined variable and the other will set itself with empty string

Comment: `un` never changes. What's `response`?

Comment: Are there any asynchronous operations like ajax  involved? without more code context what you are showing should work fine when proper values passed to `init()`

Comment: To be honest, I'm very new to js so I'm not 100% sure. But I can tell you that the relevant part is pure js.

Comment: Then show us more code context ... where you set it and where you try to access those variables after you set them. Numerous reasons you could be running into problems and we can't guess

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `init(response, un)` with two variables as parameters, but the first variable `response` has not been defined, and the second variable `un`, you've defined as an empty string `''` at the beginning of the code.

Call `init()` with two non-empty strings, and you'll see that the global variables `un` and `re` get updated correctly.

```js
var re = '';
var un = '';

function init(response_string, username_string) {
   re = response_string;
   un = username_string;
}

init("test1","test2");
console.log(re);
console.log(un);
```

Comment: I suspect OP has a synchronicity issue also

Comment: They are both non-empty strings. I can even do `console.log(response_string)` in the init() function and I get the correct string as output, I just can't update the global variables.

Comment: @b3nj4m1n you haven't posted enough code for others to be able to reproduce and thus solve the issue.